# Programmatically enable asserts on classes already loaded

Tags: java, junit, assert, assertions

As mentioned in the first comment of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5558769/1086540), using `java.lang.ClassLoader.setDefaultAssertionStatus(boolean)` only enables asserts for newly-loaded classes.

**Is there any way to enable asserts on classes already loaded?**

The unit test that I use to validate this is the following (JUnit)

```
@Test(expected = AssertionError.class)
public void testAssertsEnabled() {
  assert false;
  log.info("asserts were not enabled. Trying to enable them");
  enableAsserts(); //setDefaultAssertionStatus doesn't work since this class was already loaded
  assert false;
}
```