# Why is "assert false" not causing AssertionError when assertion are activated programmatically?

Tags: java, assertion

If I activate assertions following the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/806-7930/6jgp65ikr/index.html#assert-6)

```
ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().setDefaultAssertionStatus(true);
ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().setPackageAssertionStatus("richtercloud.java.assertion.ignored", true);
System.out.println(String.format("desired assertion status: %b",
        NewMain.class.desiredAssertionStatus()));
assert false;
System.out.println("assertion has been ignored");
```

in the `main` method of a class `richtercloud.java.assertion.ignored.NewMain`, I see from the printed statement that `assert false` doesn't cause an `AssertionError` like it's caused if I package `NewMain` in a JAR and run it with `java -ea -jar java-assertion-ignored-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar richtercloud.java.assertion.ignored.NewMain`.

Other questions regarding programmatic enabling of assertion [only suggest to not use assertions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558731/how-to-programmatically-enable-assert) which is obviously not a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm understanding the documentation correctly, you have to set assertion status before loading the class; in this example you have already loaded the class, so your `setDefaultAssertionStatus(true)` has no effect.

[Quoting from the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/806-7930/6jgp65ikr/index.html#assert-6) (my italics):

> Each class loader maintains a **default assertion status**, a boolean value that determines whether assertions are, by default, enabled or disabled in new classes that are *subsequently initialized* by the class loader.

Therefore, setting the default assertion status will only affect subsequently-loaded classes, not the currently executing one.